# Does this condition imply the Lindeberg condition?

Tags: probability-theory

Given a double array of random variables $X_{nj}, j=1,\dots, k_n, n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, 
suppose

- for each $n$, $X_{nj}, j=1,\dots, k_n$ are independent,
- each $X_{nj}$ has finite mean $\mu_{nj}$ and finite variance $\sigma_{nj}$.

Define  $S_n := \sum_{j=1}^{k_n} X_{nj}$ and  $s_n := \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{k_n} \mathrm{var} X_{nj}}$.

Now there are two versions of sufficient conditions for Lindeberg-Feller Central Limit Theorem:

1. From Kai Lai Chung's A Course in Probability Theory, the Lindeberg
   condition is defined as $$ \forall \epsilon >0, \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{k_n} \mathrm{E} [(X_{nj} - \mu_{nj})^2 I_{\{|X_{nj} - \mu_{nj}| > \epsilon s_n\}} ] }{s_n^2} = 0.$$
2. In Theorem D.19 of William Greene's Econometric Analysis ([p112 of his appendix D file](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/wgreene/Econometrics/appendix-d.doc) or [Theorem 11 on page 14  of this note](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ583/asymptoticsprimer.pdf) ), the Lindeberg condition is replaced with  $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{\max_{j=1,\dots,k_n}\sigma_{nj}^2}{s_n^2} = 0$$ $$\lim_{n \to \infty}
       \frac{s_n^2}{n} < \infty. $$ (Note: (1) The book
   deals with a sequence of random variables, but here I take the
   liberty to generalize it for a double array of random variables.
   Please correct me if I am wrong. (2) I have also changed the notation a bit.)

   **Added:** In the book, instead of $\frac{\max_{j=1,\dots,k_n}\sigma_{nj}^2}{s_n^2}$, it writes $ \frac{\max_{j=1,\dots,k_n}\sigma_{nj}}{\sqrt{k_n} s_n}$. This is said to be a [typo](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~wgreene/Text/Errata/ERRATA7.htm), and it should be $ \frac{\max_{j=1,\dots,k_n}\sigma_{nj}}{ s_n}$. And $ \frac{\max_{j=1,\dots,k_n}\sigma_{nj}}{ s_n}$ converges to finite, if and only if  $ \frac{\max_{j=1,\dots,k_n}\sigma_{nj}^2}{ s_n^2}$ converges to finite. (Note: I have changed the notation a bit.)

I wonder what relations are between these two versions of Lindeberg(-Feller) CLT?

Is the version in Greene's book a special case of that in Chung's? (I can see this is true when the double array is a sequence of identically distributed random variables.)

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

The Lindeberg condition is weaker than the one given in Greene's book, i.e. Greene's condition implies the Lindeberg condition. The Lindeberg-Feller CLT states that (let's just use one sequence) the Lindeberg condition holds *if and only if* (1) $\frac{\sum (X_i - \mu_i)}{s_n} \stackrel{d}{\to} N(0, 1)$ and (2) $\frac{\max_{1 \le i \le n} \sigma_i}{s_n} \to 0$. Greene's condition takes (2) as an assumption and derives (1), so the Lindeberg condition must hold. The same thing works for triangular arrays.

EDIT: The above is predicated on the fact that the condition in Greene, as given, is correct, which I was somewhat wary of; the other question posted by OP related shows similar reservations from other answerers.